# .NET Core + Angular-CLI App - can't pass data from api to components

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, angular-cli, single-page-application

I'm building an ASP .NET Core App with Angular-CLI using this [tutorial](https://dustinewers.com/angular-cli-with-net-core/).

App works great, I got pre-build event to ng build before starting the app in VS, it works OK. I also can successfully get to my API over localhost:port/api/[controller] (in this case it would be Contacts as it's supposed to be a contact book).

Now, I'm trying to have Angular get the data directly from API. For this reason, I created a IContact interface, a ContactService and I pass it onto ContactComponent which is supposed to display it.

I might be making a silly mistake here (my skills are very basic), but for some reason I don't even see the object .json coming in through the network logs when I run the app (before trying to pass it to the view I'm trying to ensure I'm getting the data from the API first).

I might be doing something wrong (so I encourage you to reply even if you think you might be saying silly-obvious stuff) but here's my questions:

- Should my code below work (not attaching imports though, I think I got all of them but check me ;-))? I'm not talking super-efficient or stuff, just basic to get the job done.
- What is the best way to see if service to getAPI is working? Would that be network logging in your browser if you just import the service into the component and try to call the get method? Or is there another way?
- Is my logic and approach towards the general architecture of the app OK or am I getting something wrong? :-)

contact.service.ts

```
const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

public getContacts(): Observable<IContact[]> {
    return this.http.get(API_URL)
        .map((response: Response) => <IContact[]>response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')
  }
}
```

icontact.ts

```
export interface IContact {
 id: number;
 firstName: string,
 lastName: string,
 address: string,
 telephone: string
}
```

contact.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-contact',
    templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css'],
    providers: [ContactService]
})

export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

    private _contactService: ContactService;
    private contactlist: IContact[];

    constructor() {
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this._contactService.getContacts()
            .subscribe((contacts) => { this.contactlist = contacts });

  }
}
```

Any other code requirements or anything - let me know. All feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get an answer of the API? Can you check via Network/Debug section in your browser?

Comment: I don't think so: https://imgur.com/a/eEL1f

the json I'm looking for should have 5 different contacts provided, that's not the one ;-)

Comment: Did you consider a CORS-Issue? I can't read anything on the picture you linked.

Comment: No CORS required here due to project setup - see the one before last paragraph on the correct answer. It was only a matter of incorrect Angular service code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have slightly changed your code.

File *icontact.ts*. I have made `IContact` a simple type. You can make it an interface back to support your object shape.

```
export type IContact = string;
```

File *contact.service.ts*. We call the `/api/values` API that is created by default in a new ASP.NET Core Web API project if you follow the tutorial you mentioned.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { IContact } from "./icontact";

const API_URL = '/api/values'; // environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  public getContacts(): Observable<IContact[]> {
    return this.http.get(API_URL)
      .map(response => <IContact[]>response.json());
  }
}
```

File *contact.component.ts*. The template simply displays the list.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ContactService } from "./contact.service";
import { IContact } from "./icontact";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  template: '<div *ngFor="let contact of contactList">{{contact}}</div>',
  providers: [ContactService]
})

export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  private contactList: IContact[];

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe(
      (contacts) => { this.contactList = contacts; },
      (error) => { console.log(error); }
    );
  }
}
```

File *app.component.html*. Display your component on the application's page.

```
<app-contact>Wait...</app-contact>
```

File *app.module.ts*. Import HttpModule. That fixes one of the error messages on your screenshot.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactComponent } from "./contact.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ContactComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the *Configure* method in *Startup.cs*, make sure you put the `app.Use(...)` call before `app.UseStaticFiles()`.

Since you serve your Angular app from wwwroot by a ASP.NET Core middleware, the host is the same for the Angular app and the Web API, so you don't need to configure CORS for that setup.

By the way, you may be interested in taking a look at the [Angular CLI Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyFomin.AngularCLIProjectTemplate) on Visual Studio Marketplace. (Disclaimer: I'm the author.) The Item Template supports your project setup out-of-the-box.

Comment: This has done it! Thank you so much! I can see the object coming through finally: https://imgur.com/a/Spm99
I didn't do it exactly exactly like you said here, but fixing getContacts method and constructor on contact component did the job. 
Now I'm fighting with the display, as I can't get the contact to display properly on the page ;-)